# Hash::check in Laravel 5 is not working, always return false?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authentication

I use hash check to compare between current password which is inputted by the user and current password which is stored in the database (Bcrypt)

Here is my source code

```
    $user = User::findOrFail($request->id);
    if (Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) { 
       $user->fill([
        'password' => Hash::make($request->newPassword)
        ])->save();

       $request->session()->flash('success', 'Password changed');
        // return redirect()->route('your.route');
       echo "Hash match";

    } else {
        $request->session()->flash('error', 'Password does not match');
        // return redirect()->route('your.route');
        echo "Hash does not matched";
    }
```

My problem is the Hash:check always return false ("Hash does not matched")

I put the variable in hash check like this

```
Hash::check(new password plain text, bcrypt value in db)
```

Before the Hash check is called. I try to print the variable to investigate why it not working. I found my plain text of the new password is already sent and I already got the bcrypt password from the database as well. Everything looks fine it should be worked. I don't know what is my mistake. I follows a lot of topic on this site to solve my problem as I tried it does not work for me. Anyone, please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Before using Hash::check , you have to handle this request.
$user = User::findOrFail($request->id);
whether $user returning record or not.

Comment: `if ($user && Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {`

Comment: Can you show the result of $user and $request->all(); Just to be sure.

Comment: I added this

    echo "Current password = " . $user->password. "User ID" . $user->id; 

Here is the result

    Current password = $2y$10$9O1EzE4SxU7pZWBZd3KmGursvfuMROfe/DCG5jmNfLroOw66Vm5bSUser ID1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this with default Login Controller provided by auth,then you need not use this. Its automatically done by laravel itself.

Comment: Yes I use default auth but, I created inside HomeController
What do you mean "you need not use this. Its automatically done by laravel itself." and how can I solve this?

Answer (score -1):

You're using the wrong argument order.

*Try this*,

```
if (Hash::check($user->password, $request->password))
```

Comment: The request from the client is the plain text. It has not hashed value.